# Logical indexing and subtracting from another array

Tags: matlab

I have one array called `forecast_growth`. I have another two arrays one is a confidence interval for the upper values called `ci_upper` & the last array is the lower confidence interval `ci_lower`. All the arrays are `310x1`.

What I want to do is where the values in the `forecast_growth` array are below the corresponding values in the `ci_lower` array find the difference between the growth value and the lower limit and return this to a new array.

So far I have the line below which returns all the values less than the `ci_lower` which is not quite want I require.

```
obs_outside_ci_lower = forecast_growth(forecast_growth < ci_lower);
```

**update - added some data as an example**

```
forecast_growth     ci_upper   ci_lower     rows I would like returned  values I would like returned
5                   8          3
9                   10         4
3                   7          4            Yes                         (4-3) = 1
5                   12         7            Yes                         (7-5) = 2
6                   9          4
```

So above I would like an array would return me two values. The two values where the forecast growth is below the ci_lower limit. The actual value I would like to be returned for these two rows is the ci_lower value minus the forecast growth value.

Comment: Why do you want then the `ci_upper`?

Comment: @tashuhka I need the ci_upper too however I only need to see how the lower or upper is done and I can replicate myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're after:

```
ind = forecast_growth < ci_lower;
ci_lower(ind) - forecast_growth(ind)
```

Note that `ind` will basically be your "rows I would like returned" column.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of the data, thanks